# iOS AVAudioSession applying high-pass filter

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

I have an app that uses `AVAudioSession` with `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` to capture mic input. I'm looking to apply high pass (and possibly other) filters to the captured audio data, but cannot find any good documentation about this subject, especially with something that uses AVAudioSession for data capture. Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this question is not actual for you 4 yeas later, but for future asking...

[AudioSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is an intermediate between your application and iOS system media daemon, it does not record or play audio itself, it just sets up some audio preferences. For your purpose look at [AudioUnit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) or [AudioQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioEssentials/CoreAudioEssentials.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003577-CH10-SW32). If all you need is just audio capturing, try high-level API like [AVAudioRecord](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiorecorder).

Hope it will help for someone.